# How would a cellular phone call be connected if there are two phones with the same number?

Tags: spoofing, cellular

In the 2004 movie "Primer", the a character goes back in time, and there are two copies of him, both with a cell phone. The character receives a phone call initially, and then receives the same phone call again at the same point after going back in time.

Following this, the characters are concerned that they have broken the timeline. Did the first version of him still receive the call? Has the timeline branched now? They debate for some time about how cellular calls are connected. I'm also interested in this question.

**How does the cellular network connect a call?** Does it do a search along the towers and connect to the first phone it finds? What if both are connected to the same tower? Does it choose the one with a higher received power?

In general, this seems like it could be a security exploit. If I can mimic someone else's phone to the cellular network, I could intercept their phone calls or text messages. This is the closest StackExchange site I could find to ask this on.

Comment: Every cell phone has a unique SIM card, and the phone number is associated with the SIM card.  As you roam, the phone connects to the nearest cell tower, and the cell tower identifies the phone by the SIM card.  When a call is made to the phone number, the cell carrier routes the call to the cell tower that the phone phone is connected to.  To have two phones with the same number would require two identical copies of the same SIM card.  My guess is that if the carrier saw two phones connected to two different cell towers, each with the same SIM card - then it would kick both off the network.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=How+does+the+cellular+network+connect+a+call

Comment: That wasn't meant to be unkind. This is not the right place for this question. You are asking how phones register themselves to the network so that incoming calls can find the device. The link shows that there are numerous sources that answer you. Also, that your question, if asked directly, has numerous answers for you.